# Getting the ListView ItemCheck to stop!

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview, .net-3.5

Following some SO advice I have tried the following on the ItemCheck event of a ListView control:

```
private void lstTasks_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
     ...some code

     return;
     }
```

The idea being that that **return;** will cancel the event

...but does running some code before the blank **return;** negate the desired result?

I want to use the **ItemCheck** event because it allows me to pull data via e.Index from the ListView and run some updates.  When I return to the ListView the **ItemCheck** hasn't finished firing and will often crash the program because it can't find the desired index number due to the updates removing that item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `return;` will not cancel the event.

Instead, you can set `e.NewValue` to `CheckState.Checked` or `CheckState.Unchecked`.