# CheckedListBox Action ItemCheck to remove items?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

When a box that is checked is unchecked I want to remove that item. The trouble is check/unchecking seems to happen after the ItemCheck method is called. So, when I remove an item that messes up the e.Index so it does the check/uncheck on the item after the one I remove or throws an error if it is the last one.

I found this: [Getting the ListView ItemCheck to stop!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233703/getting-the-listview-itemcheck-to-stop) which has the tip of resetting the e.NewValue which partially works, but it still throws an error when I remove the last item.

The reason I have not simply used one of the mouse events is that I want keyboard navigation to still be possible just in case.

Here is the code I have now.

```
private void checked_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                checked.Items.RemoveAt(e.Index);
                e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the only problem you're still experiencing is the call to `e.NewValue` after you remove the last item, right?  If that's the case, try this:

```
private void checked_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        checked.Items.RemoveAt(e.Index);

        // If there are no items left, skip the CheckState.Checked call
        if (checked.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
        }             
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok - I got it to work, though I'm not sure how pretty it is.  I used the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
private void checked_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckedListBox clb = (CheckedListBox)sender;
    int index = clb.SelectedIndex;

    // When you remove an item from the Items collection, it fires the SelectedIndexChanged
    // event again, with SelectedIndex = -1.  Hence the check for index != -1 first, 
    // to prevent an invalid selectedindex error
    if (index != -1 && clb.GetItemCheckState(index) == CheckState.Unchecked)
    {
        clb.Items.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

I've tested this in VS 2010 and it works.

Comment: That is pretty much the problem. Your idea is good, but even though the if statement stops my code from changing e.NewValue it seems that the default code for checking/unchecking still executes and gives a NullReferenceException. If that code could be stopped I would be good. Would there be some way to override the default code?

Comment: @Simon The Cat - give me 15 or 20 minutes to try a couple things out, and I'll post an update if I get this fixed.

Comment: @Simon The Cat - Ok, so it took me an hour, but I've got a solution that should work for you.

Comment: Hey, that works great! Thank you for taking the hour to figure that out. I was hitting a brick wall on that one.